# Set HTML stylesheet from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I need to set from JavaScript the *overflow* attribute to *scroll* in the html,body stylesheet part in the screenshot below and not in the element stylesheet part.

[image: Developer Tools Inpsector]

However, the following code sets it in the element part even though it seems the code should have set it in the body part. How can I address the html,body part ?

```
function expand() 
{
    document.body.style.overflow = "scroll";
}
```

Comment: "though it seems the code should have set it in the body part" — You're addressing the `style` property **of the element** not the stylesheets.